# Get recent posts with thumbnail

Tags: functions, post-thumbnails

I want to ger several recent posts. So I use wp_get_recent_posts. But I get only first image.

```
<?php $args = array( 'numberposts' => '3' );

$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($args);
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">' . $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
        the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, the condition is always returning false because you are not passing the post id to the function [`has_post_thumbnail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_post_thumbnail/) and the function always getting the default value which is `null`.

`has_post_thumbnail( $recent["ID"] )`.

Same with the function [`get_the_post_thumbnail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/).

`get_the_post_thumbnail( $recent["ID"] )`.

```
$args = array( 'numberposts' => '3' );

$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($args);

foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
   if ( has_post_thumbnail( $recent["ID"]) ) {
      echo  get_the_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"],'thumbnail');
    }
}
```

But if you use the functions `has_post_thumbnail();` and `get_the_post_thumbnail()` inside the WordPress [`The_Loop`](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) then you don't need to pass the post id.

```
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => '3' );
$recent_posts = new WP_Query($args);
while( $recent_posts->have_posts() ) { 

   $recent_posts->the_post() ; 

   if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
      echo  get_the_post_thumbnail();
    }
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to use `the_post_thumbnail`, you need to initialize a loop. So more like this:

```
<?php 
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => '3' );
$recent_posts = new WP_Query($args);
while( $recent_posts->have_posts() ) :  
    $recent_posts->the_post() ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a> 
        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail') ?>
        <?php endif ?>    
    </li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); # reset post data so that other queries/loops work ?>
```

(I put the thumbnail inside the `<li>` tags because anything besides `<li>` inside a `<ol>` or `<ul>` is invalid html.)